# Laravel Yajra Datatables not render all columns with HTML

Tags: php, laravel, handlebars.js, yajra-datatable

I'm using Yajra Datatables in Laravel and I need to render four columns with HTML code but only 3 of them are been rendered successfully.

!I can't find out why the column "interest" is not rendered.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLxVr.jpg)

Here is the code for that column (stackoverflow can't let me publish all method):

```php
        return DataTables::of($users)
            ->addColumn('interests', function($query) {
                $userData = UserData::where('user_id', $query->id)->first();
                if(empty($userData->interests) || is_null($userData->interests))
                    return '<a href="javascript:;">No iterests selected</a>';

                $html = '';
                $list = Interests::List();

                $myInterestsIDs = explode('|', $userData->interests);

                foreach($myInterestsIDs as $id)
                {
                    if(is_null($id) || empty($id))
                        continue;

                    $html .= '<span class="badge badge-secondary">' . $list[$id-1] . '</span>';
                }

                return $html;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['nda', 'access', 'interests', 'actions'])
            ->make(true);
    }
```

I found the reason why it's not rendering HTML. It is because **handlebars**.

```
 <script id="details-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
     <table class="table">
          <thead>
              <th>Approval</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Interests</th>
              <th>Total Access</th>
              <th>Last Access</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td>@{{approval}}</td>
                 <td>@{{status}}</td>
                 <td>@{{interests}}</td>
                 <td>@{{count_login}}</td>
                 <td>@{{last_login}}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
     </table>
 </script>
```

Comment: Maybe add it to `$html` instead of `return`ing it? What's `<a href="javascript:;">` supposed to do?

Comment: that javascript:; avoid the anchor's action

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
<td>@{{interests}}</td>
```

to

```
<td>@{{{interests}}}</td>
```

and works perfectly!